# Qsort compare function

Tags: c++, compare, qsort

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
    int (*compare)(const void*,const void*));
```

Why does the qsort function want an int* return type for compare when the compare function is of type int?

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    if ( *(MyType*)a <  *(MyType*)b ) return -1;
    if ( *(MyType*)a == *(MyType*)b ) return 0;
    if ( *(MyType*)a >  *(MyType*)b ) return 1;
}
```

Can someone explain this please, my program wont compile because of this. Thanks! 
Code taken from this source: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/

Comment: It doesn't want an `int *`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not returning an `int *`, it is returning an `int`.  `compare` is a *function pointer*.  The `*` you are seeing there defines it as a function pointer.  (Note the parentheses around `*compare`.)

[cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) parse of `int (*compare)(const void*,const void*))`:

> declare compare as pointer to function (pointer to const void, pointer to const void) returning int

This would be the parameter declaration if it were a pointer to a function returning an `int *`:

```
int * (*compare)(const void*,const void*))
```

---

If your code is not compiling then it is for some other reason.  Consider adding the error message to your question (or creating a new question) if you would like more specific advice about the compiler error.

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html. In the "Function pointers in the wild" section, there is no sign of a function pointer. How does the compiler know that when int_sorter just returns an int?